# How to pass testcase parameter into a pytest fixture that is used from one function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

if there is anyway i can replace 3 static function as pytest.fixture ? so I can pass argument from testcase to customer_preset fixture then to another fixture `setup_customer_name`, `setup_customer_address`, `setup_customer_number` ?

my test sequence is

```
1: run testcase, pass argument as list.
2: parse argument one by one and pass each argument to each function like `setup_customer_name`, `setup_customer_address`, `setup_customer_number`
3:return the query result from each function back to testcase
```

and I have following code

I know there is another way that I can just pass argument from testcase and make `setup_customer_name`, `setup_customer_address`, `setup_customer_number` as fixture indirect to fixture. but just based on my codebased now I cannot really do that

```
import pytest
class TestCustomer:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('customer_preset',
                             [dict(name='apple', addr='apple_address', number='apple_number'),
                              dict(name='google', addr='google_address', number='google_number'),
                              dict(name='amazon', addr='amazon_address', number='amazon_number')],
                              indirect=['customer_preset'])
    def test_customer(self, customer_preset):
        print(customer_preset)
        pass

class TestPreset:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="function")
    def customer_preset(self, request):
        """
        """
        name = self.setup_customer_name(request.param.get('name'))
        addr = self.setup_customer_address(request.get('addr'))
        number = self.setup_customer_number(request.get('number'))
        return name, addr, number

    def setup_customer_name(self, name):
        #do some pre set query number name
        return

    def setup_customer_address(self, address):
        #do some pre set addr
        return
    def setup_customer_number(self, number):
        #do some pre set number
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am getting from your question is you need to pass 3 values from test to fixture and you want to do some process on those 3 values and get back to test.

If so, you can define functions under fixture as below.

To use the values in test which is actually defined in fixture you can use request parameter.

Here as scope of fixture is function so you can define variable as request.instance.variable_name if scope would be class then it should be request.cls.variable_name and using same syntax you can access the variable inside test.

Here, in functions i am adding "!!!!!" to your actual data. You can modify the function as per your requirement

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def customer_preset(request):
    def setup_customer_name(name):
        # do some pre set query number name
        return name+" !!!!!"

    def setup_customer_address(address):
        # do some pre set addr
        return address+" !!!!!"

    def setup_customer_number(number):
        # do some pre set number
        return number+" !!!!!"

    print(request.getfixturevalue('customer_preset_data'))
    request.instance.name = setup_customer_name(request.getfixturevalue('customer_preset_data')['name'])
    request.instance.addr = setup_customer_address(request.getfixturevalue('customer_preset_data')['addr'])
    request.instance.number =setup_customer_number(request.getfixturevalue('customer_preset_data')['number'])




class TestCustomer:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('customer_preset_data',
                             [dict(name='apple', addr='apple_address', number='apple_number'),
                              dict(name='google', addr='google_address', number='google_number'),
                              dict(name='amazon', addr='amazon_address', number='amazon_number')]
                              )
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures('customer_preset')
    def test_customer(self,customer_preset_data,request):
        print( request.instance.name)
        print( request.instance.addr)
        print( request.instance.number)
```

Comment: yes...but my questions is more like how can I pass data from test to one fixture and to another fixture. so it is pretty much to write `setup_customer_name`, `setup_customer_address`, .. as fixture and get value from `customer_preset`